# Why isn't my function working?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, for-loop, appendchild

My code was working fine moments ago (counting how many times it found your word inside a text box), and now it's not anymore. I might have removed or added something by accident. Looked thoroughly and couldn't spot why it's not working:

Edit: Added CSS and here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ovwj1u1/).

### HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="table">
        <div id="big_block">
            <div class="top_block">
                <div id="left">
                    <form>
                        <input id="box_top" type="text" placeholder="Type your word here">
                    </form>
                    <button id="bt_1" onclick="count()"> <strong>Find</strong>

                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom_block">
                <div id="textDiv">
                    <textarea id="textBox" placeholder="Insert your text here."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript:

```
function count() {
    //I define both word and text here based on the input boxes.
    var word = document.getElementById("box_top").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
    var hits = [];

    //Then I push the word to an array everytime I find it:
    for (var x = 0; x < text.length; x++) {
        if (text.substr(x, word.length) === word) {
            hits.push(word);
        }
    }

    //Here I define what the paragraphs will look like so later I can append them on conditions
    var p0 = document.createElement("p");
    var n0 = document.createTextNode("You didn't type a word!");
    p0.appendChild(n0);

    var pt = document.createElement("p");
    var nt = document.createTextNode("You didn't insert a text!");
    pt.appendChild(nt);

    var p1 = document.createElement("p");
    var n1 = document.createTextNode(word + " wasn't found!");
    p1.appendChild(n1);

    var p2 = document.createElement("p");
    var n2 = document.createTextNode(word + " was found once.");
    p2.appendChild(n2);

    var p3 = document.createElement("p");
    var n3 = document.createTextNode(word + " was found " + hits.length + " times!");
    p3.appendChild(n3);

    var rightDiv = document.getElementById("right");
    //Below, before I appending something, I remove anything that is in it.
    rightDiv.removeChild(rightDiv.firstChild);

    //My condition: depending on the array length, I'll append a different paragraph to my div.
    if (!word) {
        rightDiv.appendChild(p0);
    } else if (!text) {
        rightDiv.appendChild(pt);
    } else {
        if (hits.length === 0) {
            rightDiv.appendChild(p1);
        } else if (hits.length === 1) {
            rightDiv.appendChild(p2);
        } else {
            rightDiv.appendChild(p3);
        }

    }
}
```

### CSS

```
#outer{
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

#table{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
    }

#big_block{
    height: 260px;
    width: 480px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    }

.top_block{
    margin-left:10px;
    height:130px;
    width:460px;
    }
.bottom_block{
    height:40%;
    }

#right{
    margin-left:5px;
    height:100px;
    width:220px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:#D1FFFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity: 0.5
    }
#right p{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 33px;
    font-size: 1em;
    }

#left{
    background-color:#3399FF;
    height:100px;
    width:235px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:10px

    }

form {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:0
    }   

#box_top:hover{
    background-color:#FDFFFD
    }

#bt_1 {
    height:35px;
    width:70px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius:5px;
    }

#bt_1:hover {
    height:35px;
    width:70px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#d8dfd9
    }

#textDiv {
    margin-left:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px
    ;position:relative
    }

#textBox{
    width:460px;
    height:100px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the developer console?

Comment: @Pointy How do I do that? Sorry I'm new to coding and started just recently.

Comment: Hit the F12 key and you'll get debugging tools. Exactly how they work varies from browser to browser, but it's definitely worth your time to get familiar with the tools. It's like flying blind without them.

Comment: @Pointy Ohh, so that's what the F12 key does? I always knew something was up with it but had no clue! Thanks, I'll take my time to study this then so I can debug my future codes easily!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to remove content from "rightDiv" when it's empty, so you're getting an error. The code to do that should probably look like:

```
while (rightDiv.firstChild)
    rightDiv.removeChild(rightDiv.firstChild);
```

*Always* check the developer console when code doesn't seem to work as you expect.

Comment: I think first child should give just one node, so what is the need of `while`.

Comment: @Mritunjay it's more future-proof. If it only has one node, then there's no harm done. It's up to the OP of course :)

Comment: Thank you. Working fine now.

@Mritunjay your suggestion is nice too.

Answer (score 0):

If `div` doesn't contain a child it's throwing an error. Check if child exists remove the child.

use this

```
rightDiv.firstChild && rightDiv.removeChild(rightDiv.firstChild);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/5ovwj1u1/1/)